# How do I configure HikariCP and Dropwizard/Coda-Hale metrics in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp, codahale-metrics

Reading [the instructions](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics) on the HikariCP wiki about how to enable the Dropwizard metrics, it says to just configure a `MetricsRegistry` instance in `HikariConfig` or `HikariDatasource`.

Problem is, in Spring Boot, all the configuration is handled by autoconfiguration so I'm not manually configuring the HikariCP pool at all.

Any instructions on how to do this? Do I have to completely override the autoconfiguration by defining my own bean and setting all the settings in a `@Configuration` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out by manually configuring HikariCP in a java configuration file. That allowed me to get a reference to the Spring Boot MetricRegistry, which I could then set in HikariConfig. Here's my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.connectionTestQuery}")
    private String connectionTestQuery;

    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        Properties dsProps = new Properties();
        dsProps.setProperty("url", dataSourceUrl);
        dsProps.setProperty("user", user);
        dsProps.setProperty("password", password);

        Properties configProps = new Properties();
        configProps.setProperty("connectionTestQuery", connectionTestQuery);
        configProps.setProperty("driverClassName", driverClassName);
        configProps.setProperty("jdbcUrl", dataSourceUrl);

        HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(configProps);
        hc.setDataSourceProperties(dsProps);
        hc.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        return new HikariDataSource(hc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Or let Spring Boot configure your data source, @Autowire the DataSource and MetricRegistry in your @Configuration/@SpringBootApplication class and wire them together in a @PostConstruct:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;


@PostConstruct
public void setUpHikariWithMetrics() {
    if(dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource) {
        ((HikariDataSource) dataSource).setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better I believe, keep everything else intact and plug in the metrics in the end. Nice answer!

Comment: When I try this, I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started.  Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes."